# How Bash built-in control structure / command redirection works

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, io-redirection

I'm interested how redirection is technically implemented with bash built-in control structures and functions.

For example, I have the following command

```
while read line; do echo $line; done < lines.txt | tac > ~/reversed.txt
```

What mechanism connects the stdin (lines.txt) to `read` command (argument of `while`) and what connects `do` body to stdout (pipe)? There are clearly some contextual rules applied (contra external command redirection), but what exactly are those rules and how bash technically implements them?

Comment: You can see that with `strace`: In the shell to be monitored: `echo $$` Somewhere else: `strace -p 12345 -f`

Answer (score 3):

Usually, UNIX shells just open the required files with `open`, then `fork` themselves, then `dup2` the previously obtained fd's to stdin/stdout/stderr (0/1/2) so they're handled accordingly by the program they `execve` later. It might be different with builtin commands in order to improve performance (as `fork` and `execve` are quite expensive), but the semantics is the same.

If you mean the command line parsing rules, though, it's described in POSIX. They don't discern builtins and external programs.

Comment: Yes, I mean the parsing *and* the evaluation of my example regarding of connecting the IO. If these weren't built-in's but executable, input would be fed to `while` command, not the `read`. I'm looking for insight how bash evaluates this whole statement and connect things together.

Comment: @TuomasToivonen `while` is not a builtin command but a flow control keyword. All the bash builtin commands may be found in the man, /SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS. The flow control is described in POSIX.

Answer (score 1):

Redirecting file descriptor *d0* to or from a file involves the following steps:

1. Open the file. The file is opened on some file descriptor *d1*.
2. Duplicate the descriptor *d0* to a currently-unused file descriptor *d2* which is larger than *d0*. This can be done with the `F_DUPFD` command of the [`fcntl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html) system call. If *d0* is not open then do nothing for this step.
3. Duplicate *d1* to *d0*. This can be done with `F_DUPFD` or with [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup2.html).
4. Close *d1*.

The reason the duplication shuffle is needed is that applications don't get to choose the file descriptor when opening the file. Steps 2–4 can be omitted if *d1* = *d0* but the shell can't guarantee this.

When the redirection applies to an external command, it is performed in the child process, after the child process has been created with [`fork`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) but before executing the external command with [`execve`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_(system_call)). When the redirection applies to an internal shell command (e.g. a function call, a loop, etc.), these steps have to be performed in the original process¹, and the shell needs to restore the original file descriptor state after the redirected command completes, by duplicating *d2* back to *d0* and closing *d2* (or just closing *d0* if it wasn't initially open).

A pipe involves similar steps, but it is a bit more complicated because creating the pipe creates two file descriptors (the read end and the write end) and there are two subprocesses.

1. Create a pipe with [`pipe`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html). The `pipe` system call returns a pair of file descriptors {*r*, *w*}.
2. In the left-hand side of the pipe:

   1. Close *r*.
   2. Do the duplication shuffle to move *w* to 1.
3. In the right-hand side of the pipe:

   1. Close *w*.
   2. Do the duplication shuffle to move *r* to 0.
4. In shells that execute both sides of the pipe in subprocesses, the parent process closes *r* and *w*, then waits for the two sides of the pipe to terminate.

   In shells that execute the right-hand side of the pipe in the parent process, the shell waits for the left-hand side to terminate, then closes 0 and restores the original file descriptor at 0.

You can look at what shells do by reading their source code, or by following them in operation with a debugger. For example, on Linux, look the system calls in action with

```
strace sh -c '…'
```

¹  <sub>Ancient shells (before POSIX) executed redirected complex commands in a subprocess, so they didn't require any redirection restoration.</sub>

Comment: "When the redirection applies to an external command, it is performed in the child process [...]" So, contrary to the case of internal shell commands, no need to restore any file descriptor here after the execution of the external command, file descriptors just get destroyed when the child process terminates, correct?

Comment: @TheQuark Correct. Although strictly speaking, that's an implementation detail: a shell _could_ do redirection-fork-unredirection if it wanted.

Comment: Great detailed answer overall. For a complete understanding, one might need to be aware of the interplay between [file descriptors](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_166) and [open file description](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html), and the fact that a child process inherits the file descriptors of the parent process (see [open(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html)). – Just adding this here as reference.