# Does firejail rely on the application crashing out and why can't we use named pipes to .Xauthority?

Tags: linux, security, xorg, container, firejail

The purpose of jailing an Xorg application is to prevent it from accessing *@/tmp/X11/X0* and */tmp/X11/X0* and then re-using its *MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE* to steal from other apps that are connected to the X server.

The cookie is used to obtain a file-handle/socket abstraction to Xorg the first time the app connects. Were an evil hacker to segfault the app and start a shell, he won't have access to this file-handle/socket abstraction and therefore needs the original MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE from *.Xauthority* AND he needs access to the /tmp/X11/X0 file/abstract-socket TO CREATE a new Xorg CONTEXT.

The idea behind firejail and Linux namespaces is to hide these resources from him and prevent him from creating a fresh Xorg context.

To do this firejail relies on Linux Namespaces and moves the application into a new namespace where /tmp/* isn't present. It also gives the application a new bridge interface using *--net=* Therefore, the application cannot see a .Xauthority file AND it has no way of communicating with Xorg. Because the application is communicating over a bridge interface it can see the internet/assuming it's allowed but it's view will be limited by the firewall on br0 etc

The application itself USES its Xorg socket-pointer to talk to Xorg using shared memory and SO LONG as it retains this pointer it can do so indefinitely.

**So firejail security relies on the application crashing out completely from memory and LOSING it's Xorg CONTEXT/pointers?** ***But the hacker can segfault into the application and rewrite it's code and still retain the Xorg context?*** But this is a risk we have to take - maybe prevented by *Apparmor/SELinux* and monitoring systemcalls?

However why don't we use *named-pipes* instead? Create a named-pipe/.Xauthority and *export XAUTHORITY* and start the app - it'll block, so on the Server end, run something that writes the current cookie and changes it once the app has started. Therefore if the app segfaults out, the hacker is just a normal user or restricted with no cookie: there's no hope in heck of the hacker ever stealing the new cookie, especially if you clean out/nuke the user/remove all his files and start afresh every app-run.

What's firejail doing that's different from this? If he needs the app to start he has to provide the .Xauthority and socket file.. then what - does he move the app into a new NS - how does he know when to? Many apps poll the .Xauthority multiple times so how does firejail know when to hide these resources and how exactly does it hide these resources?

Answer (score 0):

> The purpose of jailing an Xorg application is to prevent it from accessing @/tmp/X11/X0 and /tmp/X11/X0 and then re-using its MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE to steal from other apps that are connected to the X server

Um ... no? If you read e.g. [this guide](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/x11-guide/),

> The sandbox replaces the regular X11 server with Xpra or Xephyr server. This prevents X11 keyboard loggers and screenshot utilities from accessing the main X11 server.

So the purpose if jailing an X application is to completely prevent it from accessing the main server, and instead letting it access a proxy server. Even if the application tries tricks with the proxy server, that won't affect the main server.

I am not sure what scenario exactly you describe, but any X application that has access to the main server somehow, even if initial authorization with MIT cookies was not done by the application itself, can then do tricks on this server, like key logging or accessing other windows. It doesn't have to crash to do that. So doing the initial authorization for the application and then preventing it from re-authorization doesn't help in any way.

Have you possibly missed that the main point of starting the jailed application in a particular way is to make it access a proxy X server?

**Edit**

> I'm just trying to understand what EXACTLY firejail's doing different from traditional xauth/.Xauthority to make the jailed app secure.

Firejail is showing the app an X server proxy, and is preventing the app from accessing the main X server. That's all. The traditional xauth mechanism is exactly the same, both between the app and the X proxy, and between the X proxy and the main X server. (And yes, *of course* the X proxy needs to access the main server, or, there needs to be a program that can access both the main X server and the X proxy. But these programs are *trusted*, unlike the app).

> and is then relying on Namespaces and to prevent that cookie from being compromised.. and as an added measure hiding the Xorg socket.

No. The point of namespaces is to make the main X server communication endpoints inaccessible. As in "they don't exist". It's not really "hiding" anything ("it's there but you can't see it"). It's no longer there, as far as the jailed application is concerned. In the same way a Docker container uses namespaces to pretend to the applications in the container that they are running in a completely different environment.

Not having the jailed app see the main X server communication endpoints would already be sufficient, but of course there's no reason why the jailed app should see valid MIT cookies for the main X server.

*Named pipes* really have nothing to do with it. Nor have crashes. Nor has the way the X authentication mechanism works.

Comment: I know that firejail and all the other Xorg-related jails use Xvfb to do their rendering - which was originally used to test Xorg clients and now it(Xvfb) has been repurposed. You can then grab the rendered data from Xvfb using x11vnc+vncviewer. Xpra is Xvfb+compositing WindowManager. Oz uses Xpra so,, it looks like Xvfb and Namespaces are sitting at the bottom of all these attempts to secure Xorg; the idea being that they can discard Xorg eventually. However this attempt at wrapping a smaller version of Xorg - Xvfb - seems to have similar problems - hence the question.

Comment: I don't understand the "problems", nor do I understand the "question". If the jailed application only sees a proxy server (no matter if a re-purposed Xvfb,  Xpra or Xephyr), then the jailed application can't access the main server. No matter how you feed it MIT cookies, via pipes, or otherwise. So, problem solved, and jailing accomplished: It can't access the main server, end of story. What is the question?

Comment: Since asking the Q, I did some googling and found this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=526678 I ran this: firejail xpra start :20 --start-child=xterm --no-daemon --exit-with-children and did a quick ps -auxww|grep xauth and I get this test     10890  0.0  0.0  26396  1292 pts/2    S+   16:11   0:00 xauth add :20 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 1b56f60e989f4ddfbc0ddf40380aca29 Which kind of answers my question.. (I was asking how firejail was getting access to the main Xorg server - yes it's using a proxy but proxy has to write to the main Xorg server). I'm on Debian so maybeit'sdifferent

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what EXACTLY firejail's doing different from traditional xauth/.Xauthority to make the jailed app secure (Barring the proxy Xvfb and Namespaces). He seems to be writing HIS COOKIE into my .Xauthority.. and is then relying on Namespaces and to prevent that cookie from being compromised.. and as an added measure hiding the Xorg socket.. but this is different from using named pipes where YOU give him a cookie.. and once the connection is established, delete it..

Comment: what is the name of the 'X proxy' process in this line: 'app and the X proxy, and between the X proxy and the main X server.'

Comment: The proxy would be either Xpra or Xephyr, according to the linked guide. If you say you've also seen Xvfb with vncviewer, then vncviewer would connect to the main X server.

Comment: right, wrt Xpra - it's a python script running in the same user space as evil app - what stops the evil app that is being proxied from injecting into Xpra and using its connectivity to Xorg to send malicious data?

Comment: Each user process runs in its virtual address space but they are the same EUID/EGID in this case. What stops the evil-app from extracting the credentials from Xpra? Using all of the linux system calls.. /coredump and look at that? evil app can strace xpra or attach to it using gdb/pdb.

Comment: How should the jailed app "inject into Xpra"? I haven't checked the details how firejail does it, but Xpra should run in such a way that the jailed app cannot access anything about Xpra except the X communication socket. If it doesn't, that's a bug, and a rather big one. Note that Xpra can't run in exactly the same namespace as the jailed app, because if it was, it wouldn't be able to connect to the main X server. So the answer to "what stops the jailed app from ..." is "it should be set up in such a way that the jailed app can't". By namespaces, or otherwise.

Comment: hence my question.. because I don't like magic and mystery when it comes to Xorg and security..

Comment: "How does firejail secure Xpra in detail" is a very different question from "does firejail rely on an application crashing", so maybe you should ask a new question. The simplest way to find out is to run firejail with Xpra, and have a look what it exactly does. Also, jail a self-written application that tries to access Xpra or "inject into it", and see what happens. I don't run Xpra here, so I can't do it for you. The simplest way would be for firejail *not* to run Xpra under the same UID.

Comment: Reading [this](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/57) firejail issue thread has me a bit worried if the firejail developers understand the issues, though ... so if you run Xpra with firejail, you should definitely have a closer look. The principle "only let the jailed app see an X proxy" is sound, but if they bungled the execution...

Answer (score 0):

So i emailed the Xorg mailing list and they were quite helpful, so this is how it all works.

*Xorg -nolisten tcp -nolisten inet -nolisten inet6 -listen unix -nolisten local  :0 -seat seat0 vt7 -novtswitch*
is the command you use to turn off listening except on UNIX Domain sockets (ripped from debian).

This will result in */tmp/X11/X0 and @/tmp/X11/X0* **abstract sockets** being created.

Xorg receives a cookie over this pipe/socket (written by the program using *Gtk/Qt-->Xlib[.Xauthority]*) and compares it, with its internal cookie, given to it by XDM. If they match Xorg will create its internal context and associate this context with the IP:Port [for tcp/ip connections] or app FD [for sockets][Named Pipes Socket/FD creation][1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450713/named-pipes-file-descriptors-and-eof).

Basically each app writing to /tmp/X11/X0 results in Xorg creating a unique FD at its end. If the app dies and exits then this FD is closed by Xorg but if the app is injected into, then this Xorg FD/context IS NOT destroyed and the virus/evil-app can spoof the app and continue talking to Xorg. If the app is using a network/tcp then this is even easier since Xorg just uses IP:Port to authenticate after XOpenDisplay/MIT-COOKIE [cookie is only used for one API call to Xorg].

The app could, if it wanted to, retain the COOKIE in its memory thus allowing the hacker to steal the COOKIE but this auth bit is Xlib's job. Firejail doesn't really guard against cookie theft. What it does is use Xvfb to render the application GUI and then send the pixmap to the Xorg server by using Xpra-which is divided into two parts - a client Xpra and a server Xpra (The Xpra docs/readme explains that bit). Because the server only sees pixmap and no API calls from the trusted-proxy/Xpra-server/client/whatever it's protected by its Burqa and therefore safe. However the rapists are still running around because Xorg's weak and pathetic with no security whatsoever :p

It's a lot of duct-tape holding it all together and its not very neat and efficient - though I guess very debatable. Xorg has 0 security besides that onetime cookie verification - it was designed for a different era so.. I haven't got anything to work so far. I suspect it'll be easier to write a bash script to do the cgroup/resource-limit and namespace rather than use firejail which uses all sorts of shady hacks and is in C for whatever reason. As for Xorg.. I need to readup on Xvfb and try to extract/send the data to Xorg via the jail.